# AutoCompleteTextView : how to stop alphabetical sorting in dropdown

Tags: android

If I enter a word "wood" in AutoCompleteTextView , then result comes in drop down list : 
"bolly wood "
"holly wood "

## "wood"

I want result like this:
"wood"
"bolly wood"
"holly wood"

AutoCompleteTextView does alphabatical sorting.How to stop this sorting???

Answer (score 0):

Did your tried this:

In the layout XML, add the following attribute to your EditText:

```
android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
```

If neither this, nor the above approaches work, then this is almost certainly a problem with the emulator and the other device, and you should contact the manufacturers directly.

See also: [android:inputType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aimeOptions) (note that EditText is a subclass of TextView, which is why this attribute also works for EditTexts).

Answer (score 0):

Use **android:completionThreshold="1"**
to show list of option while entering a single character('w')..

So possible outcome is like
**"wood"

"bolly wood"

"holly wood"**

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
 android:id="@+id/autocomplete"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_margin="10dp"
 android:paddingLeft="10dp"
 android:completionThreshold="1"
 android:textSize="18sp"
             />
```